# Good books about green's function method

Tags: reference-request, greens-functions

I am trying to learn to do Green's function calculations. Are there any good introductory books about the Green's function method?

Comment: The Green's function "method" to do what?

Comment: I am mostly interested in calculating the properties of strongly interacting systems.

Comment: Mathematical Methods for Physicists: A Comprehensive Guide. it may help  @andy90

Comment: Chapter 10 of [this version of the book that Alme999 suggested](https://books.google.ca/books?id=qLFo_Z-PoGIC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) is about Green's functions, but without knowing which property of strongly interacting systems you are trying to calculate, it's not clear whether or not this is what you want. @andy90 which property of strongly interacting systems are you trying to calculate with Green's functions? Why does it have to be with Green's functions?

Comment: "Introduction to Many-body quantum theory in condensed matter physics" by Henrik Bruus and Karsten Flensberg could be a good start.